# nested div made by dojo cannot be reached by watir Cannot Preform Native Interactions

Tags: dojo, watir, native-methods

I am using the following code, in order to display a Menu with the right click (In Selenium context menu).

```
# encoding: utf-8
require 'watir-webdriver'
b = Watir::Browser.new


b.goto 'localhost:8080/swbadmin'
b.text_field(:name => 'wb_username').set 'admin'
b.text_field(:name => 'wb_password').set 'webbuilder'
b.button(:text => 'Login').click

a = b.div(:class => 'dijitTreeNodeContainer').div(:class => 'dijitTreeIsRoot').div(:class => 'dijitTreeRow').span(:class => 'dijitTreeContent')
c= a.span(:text => 'tst')
c.right_click
```

The thing is that dijitTreeNodeContainer is made by a dojo. So i have to wait until it loads all the information, I tried to use Watir::wait.until{ span(:text => 'tst').visible ?} but it dindn't work.
With this code without the line

```
c= a.span(:text => 'tst')
```

and with c.click, I'm able to click the default TreeContent, but when I try with right click or double_click, it throws an exception ( ..cannot preform native interactions...)
This is the html code

```
<div id="dijit_layout_AccordionPane_0" class="dijitContentPane dijitAccordionContainer-child dijitAccordionContainer-dijitContentPane dijitContentPaneSingleChild" selected="true" dojotype="dijit.layout.AccordionPane" widgetid="dijit_layout_AccordionPane_0" title="" style="width: 238px; height: 76.5px;">
<div url="/swbadmin/jsp/Tree.jsp?id=mtree" jsid="mtreeStore" dojotype="dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore"></div>
<div childrenattrs="children" rootid="root" store="mtreeStore" jsid="mtreeModel" dojotype="dijit.tree.ForestStoreModel"></div>
<div id="mtree" class="dojoDndSource dojoDndTarget dojoDndContainer dijitTree" role="presentation" widgetid="mtree" tabindex="0" _dijitmenumtreemenu="1" style="width: 238px; height: 76.5px;">
<div class="dijitInline dijitTreeIndent" data-dojo-attach-point="indentDetector" style="position: absolute; top: -9999px"></div>
<div class="dijitTreeExpando dijitTreeExpandoLoading" data-dojo-attach-point="rootLoadingIndicator" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="dijitTreeContainer" role="presentation" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode" style="width: 100%;">
<div id="dijit__TreeNode_0" class="dijitTreeIsRoot dijitTreeNode dijitTreeNodeLoaded dijitLoaded" role="presentation" style="background-position: 0px 0px;" widgetid="dijit__TreeNode_0">
<div class="dijitTreeRow" role="presentation" data-dojo-attach-point="rowNode" style="padding-left: 0px; display: none;">
<div class="dijitTreeNodeContainer" style="height: auto;" role="tree" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode" aria-expanded="true" aria-multiselectable="true">
<div id="dijit__TreeNode_3" class="dijitTreeIsRoot dijitTreeNode dijitTreeNodeNotLoaded dijitNotLoaded" role="presentation" style="background-position: 0px 0px;" widgetid="dijit__TreeNode_3">
<div class="dijitTreeRow dijitTreeRowSelected" role="presentation" data-dojo-attach-point="rowNode" title="" style="padding-left: 0px;">
<span class="dijitInline dijitTreeExpando dijitTreeExpandoClosed" role="presentation" data-dojo-attach-point="expandoNode"></span>
<span class="dijitExpandoText" role="presentation" data-dojo-attach-point="expandoNodeText">+</span>
<span class="dijitTreeContent" role="presentation" data-dojo-attach-point="contentNode">
<span class="dijitInline dijitIcon dijitTreeIcon swbIconWebSite" data-dojo-attach-point="iconNode" role="presentation"></span>
<span class="dijitTreeLabel" aria-selected="true" tabindex="-1" role="treeitem" data-dojo-attach-point="labelNode,focusNode" aria-expanded="false">Demo</span>
</span>
</div>
<div class="dijitTreeNodeContainer" style="display: none;" role="presentation" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode"></div>
</div>
<div id="dijit__TreeNode_4" class="dijitTreeIsRoot dijitTreeNode dijitTreeNodeLoaded dijitLoaded" role="presentation" style="background-position: 0px 0px;" widgetid="dijit__TreeNode_4">
<div class="dijitTreeRow" role="presentation" data-dojo-attach-point="rowNode" title="" style="padding-left: 0px;">
<span class="dijitInline dijitTreeExpando dijitTreeExpandoClosed" role="presentation" data-dojo-attach-point="expandoNode"></span>
<span class="dijitExpandoText" role="presentation" data-dojo-attach-point="expandoNodeText">+</span>
<span class="dijitTreeContent" role="presentation" data-dojo-attach-point="contentNode">
<span class="dijitInline dijitIcon dijitTreeIcon swbIconWebSiteU" data-dojo-attach-point="iconNode" role="presentation"></span>
<span class="dijitTreeLabel" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1" role="treeitem" data-dojo-attach-point="labelNode,focusNode" aria-expanded="false">tst</span>
</span>
</div>
<div class="dijitTreeNodeContainer" style="height: auto; display: none;" role="group" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention which browser you're using - is it Firefox on Windows?  In that case try spawning Chrome instead:

```
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
```

If you have to stick with Firefox, try disabling native events.

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile.native_events = false
b = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :profile => profile
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using Firefox, I've already tried disabling native events but didn't work. And the other problem is that i cannot reach the second Tree Node with the text 'tst'